# Для чего аргументы псевдомассива arguments сохранять в переменную arg перед копированием в объект?

Tags: javascript, объекты, for, properties

В данном случае функция copy  копирует свойства нескольких объектов в новый  объект,а ниже её реализация.Копируются  свойства первого уровня,т.е.  вложенные объекты не обрабатываются.
Здесь первый аргумент copy – это объект, в который нужно копировать, он назван dst. Для упрощения доступа к нему можно указать его прямо в объявлении функции:
Так собственно сам вопрос для чего создавать переменную arg,почему напрямую не скопировать вот так: dst[key] = arguments[key]? Или перебрать псевдомассив с помощью цикла for in  нельзя?

```js
function copy(dst) {
  // остальные аргументы остаются безымянными
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var arg = arguments[i];
    for (var key in arg) {
      dst[key] = arg[key];
    }
  }

  return dst;
```

Answer (score 0):

Напрямую не получится. Цикл for in в данном случае перебирает свойства каждого объекта хранящегося в arguments (начиная с индекса 1, так как первым у нас хранится целевой объект).

```js
var o = {};

function copy(t, ...r) {
  for (k in r) t[k] = r[k];
}

copy(o, {name: 'John'}, {n: 42});
o //0: {name: "John"} 1: {n: 42}
```

Если  так как в примере выше, тогда он просто присвоит каждый объект в качестве свойств целевого объекта, вместо того чтобы скопировать их свойства.

П.С.:Альтернативный вариант - Object.assign();

Comment: как решился-то?

Comment: Вы как автор можете сами удалить вопрос с нулевым рейтингом.

Comment: Напрямую он просто присвоит все объекты переданные в функцию, после dst в качестве свойств dst, а не скопирует именно сами свойства.

Comment: он их и так не копирует :-)

Comment: подробнее можно?)

Comment: мне кажется в вопросе ты спросил одно, а в ответе совсем про другое :-)

Comment: _для чего создавать переменную arg_ - можно и не создавать. просто в твоем цикле всегда было б `arguments[i]` вместо нее. При этом это никакого отношения к `dst[key] = arguments[key]` не имеет, так как никакой разницы нет, присвоить сразу или сохранить сначала в переменную. И последний вопрос _Или перебрать псевдомассив с помощью цикла for in нельзя? - конечно можно.

Comment: Блин,вот такие вот лишние инициализации и порождают лишние вопросы, так ещё и на одном ресурсе как я в ответе написал  прокомментировали так,а  тут -по другому ..опять опять косяки js.lern...я бы не пользовался и не повторял темы оттуда,если бы  не относительно неплохая структуризация тем на лёрне..там перед глазами сразу все разделы и не приходится что-то конкретное искать... но и вот таких вот косяков полно